# The declaration of class in C++ combines the interface with the implementation of that interface?

Tags: c++, class, interface

I have a question about declaration of class.

I read the following lines in a paper: A C++ class declaration combines the external interface of an object with the implementation of that interface.

So, what is a external interface in C++? are there concept of interface in C++? how to understand this: A C++ class declaration combines the external interface of an object with the implementation of that interface. ?

Comment: A pure virtual class is essentially an interface only -- no implementation. So that isn't entirely accurate.

Comment: I would just interpret that to mean that the implementation derives from the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's referring to the API — i.e. the signatures of the public functions — as contrasted to the implementation — i.e. private functions and data members.

```
class T
{
   // Here are some private things.
   // You might say that these are part of
   //  the class's implementation.

   int x;
   int y;

   void foo();
   void bar();

public:
   // And here are some public things, that
   //  constitute the class's API or "interface",
   //  which is the mechanism by which you may
   //  interact with objects of this type.

   void baz();
   void boz();
};
```

Notice how they are all present, right there, in the single class definition, and they must be. "Combined".

Ultimately, though, you'd have to ask the author of the paper as the terminology level used is up to them. Conceivably they *could* be talking about inheritance heirarchies and abstract base classes... though I can't find a way to rationalise the assertion that C++ class definitions "combine" those in any real sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think the definition by the paper is a bit inaccurate. The terms *declaration*, *implementation*, *definition*, and *interface* should be used with some rigor. I will try to explain a little bit.

First of all, a class *declaration* does not specify any interface: it simply states that the class exists. For instance, these are some declarations:

```
class my_class;
struct my_structure;
template<typename T> class X;
```

A class *definition* on the other hand *declares* which are the *members* of a class (functions and data). Without entering too much into details, the term *external interface* in the sense used by the paper you quote roughly means "a specification of what can be done with objects of that class by code which belongs to functions that are *not* members of that class".

Here is an example of a class *definition*:

```
class my_class
{
public:
    void foo();
    int bar(int x) const;
private:
    void do_something();
    int data;
};
```

The term *external interface* used in the paper you mention almost certainly refers to the *public* interface, which is the list of all members of the class which have `public` visibility. All member variables and functions of a class can have one of three levels of visibility: `public`, `protected`, or `private`. I am not delving into details here, but it should be enough to say that `public` members (data or functions) are those members that can be accessed from functions which are *not* themselves members of the class, while `private` members can only be accessed from functions which *are* members of the class. The `protected` qualifier is related with inheritance and I don't think that needs to be covered to answer your question.

Now the *public interface* of class `my_class` above *declares* functions foo() and bar(), but does not yet specify their *implementation* or, in more formal terms, their *definition*. In general, member functions are not necessarily *defined* in a class definition (you can't tell what `foo()` does just by looking at the definition of `my_class`, can you?). Thus, unless you write the *body* of a member function directly after its declaration, a separate *member function definition* is necessary to specify the *implementation* of that function:

```
void my_class::foo()
{
    std::cout << "hello, i'm foo" << std::endl;
}

int my_class::bar(int x)
{
    do_something();
    x * 2 + 1;
}

void my_class::do_something()
{
    std::cout << "doing something..." << std::endl;
}
```

Due to the different visibility levels of these functions, a client code from a function external to class `my_class` can call functions `foo()` and `bar()`, because they belong to the `public` interface, but not function `do_something()`, which is declared as `private`. For instance:

```
int main()
{
    my_class c;
    c.foo(); // OK!
    c.do_something(); // ERROR!
}
```

The rationale behind the fact that some functions can be made accessible from the outside of a class and other cannot is to be found in a good design principle that goes under the name of "**information hiding**". By exposing to your clients only a set of *services* and hiding the way those services are actually *implemented* (e.g. function `bar()` invokes the `private` function `do_something()`), you create a layer of abstraction that protects client code from possible internal changes in the implementation of those services.

So finally, I believe that what the writer of the sentence "*A C++ class declaration combines the external interface of an object with the implementation of that interface*" actually wants to say is that **from the *definition* of a class you can get a hint on what are the services that class exposes to its clients ("external interface", i.e. `public` functions) *and* what are the functions and variables that are used internally to realize those services ("implementation", i.e. `private` functions and member variables)**.

I apologize if it took a bit long to finally give you the interpretation of that sentence, but I felt like some clarification was in order. Anyway, this was necessarily just a short summary of this articulated topic: I am sure you can find better sources if you google all these terms or if you buy a good book on C++.

P.S.: Also please keep in mind, that *formally* the term (and keyword!) `interface` means something very specific in C++, which requires introducing the notion of *pure virtual function*. I thought it was not the case of explaining that, as it was likely unrelated with the intended meaning of the word "interface" in the sentence you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could view the public members of a class as an external interface.

There is no `interface` in C++ as you have it in Java, for example. You can only define a base class and define some virtual member functions, which must be implemented by derived classes.

A class declaration includes `public`, `protected` and/or `private` members. The protected and private members could be seen as "implementation" details, but not necessarily as implementation of that public interface.

Answer (score 0):

The interface contains declaration of the method, and this is found in header files. This header files is correlated with some source files where appear the code for this methods. fr example, you can see how can be add a class in Eclipse CDT.